# React Navigation: How to pass a prop to a screen in a nested navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-tabnavigator, bottomtabs

In my React Native app I have the following `TabNavigator` nested inside an `AppNavigator`:

```
const TabNavigator = () => (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen component={Screen1} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
);

export const AppNavigator = () => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen component={TabNavigator}/>
    <Stack.Screen component={OtherComponent1}/>
    <Stack.Screen component={OtherComponent2}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
}
```

I want to pass the `loading` hook to `Screen1`.

**What I've tried:**

1. Putting `const TabNavigator` etc inside `AppNavigator`. The problem with this is, `AppNavigator` re-renders a lot, and therefore `Screen1` re-renders and flickers a lot.
2. Passing `loading` as a prop to `TabNavigator` and `Screen1`, like `<Stack.Screen component={() => <TabNavigator loading={loading}/>}/>` and `<Tab.Screen component={() => <Screen1 loading={props.loading}/>} />`. The problem with this is is that it gives me [this warning](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8517) about passing an inline function.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Context API to pass the value.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html